# How to count subjects on a longitudinal patient study in R?

Tags: r, count, longitudinal

I have a database with multiple patient visits, like

1
1
1
1
2
2
3
3
3
3
4
4
4
4

They are in a column (although here are shown in a row) and I would like to know how to count how many subjects do I have. Like in this case: 4

I don't know which code to use in R.

Thank you.

Comment: First of all, you should change your tag from rstudio to R. (I changed that myself)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I'm not wrong, you just want to know how many subjects you have.

In your case you have 4 subjects: 1, 2, 3 and 4.

Then, is the column that you say is stored in some `data.frame`, for example, you have one option:

```
length(unique(data$subjects))
```

Or if it's stored in a `vector`:

```
length(unique(vector.subjects))
```

I hope this is what you were looking for.

- `unique` shows the different values that you may find on the vector. In this case: 1, 2, 3 and 4.
- `length` counts the number of elements of `unique` vector (1, 2, 3 and 4)

Comment: Thanks! this works!  and sorry for the mistake. I normally use Rstudio so I thought I could tag that.

Comment: You're welcome!
Of course you use Rstudio as a viewer of R, but this doubt was about coding, not RStudio software.
If this works for you, please, tag my answer as correct in order to close the issue and give help to the people that has the same issue.